# binding function together so when one is execute the other executes

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to execute a function when another one is executed. Like they are bound together. I have tried a few things like using `bind` but this doesn't work because it is just used for changing the context.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I want to do
http://jsfiddle.net/4hdX5/

Comment: Check out http://underscorejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is make some kind of function-pool.  I did it here quick&dirty with an object literal :

```
var functionPool = {

pool: {},
add: function (name, pFunction) {
    functionPool.pool[name] = pFunction;
},
execute: function (name) {
    functionPool.pool[name].call();
}, 
executeAllBound: function(name) {
    functionPool.pool[name].call();
    // TODO 
    // then iterate over all not named name

}

};

function f1() {
    alert(42);
}

function f2() {
    alert(1337);
}

functionPool.add("firstAlert", f1);
functionPool.add("secondAlert", f2);

functionPool.execute("firstAlert");
functionPool.execute("secondAlert");

functionPool.execute1llBound("secondAlert");
```

You store them as KV-pairs, and you can execute easily one, or all, or start with one and than iterate over all other.

http://jsfiddle.net/zEq9w/

Answer (score 0):

Just call it:

```
function test () {
    alert('testing');
}
function test2 () {
    alert('testing2');
    test();
}
test2();
```

**Fiddle**: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bQbrk/)</kbd>